# Angular 2 Typescript building error with momentjs for moment.d.ts

Tags: typescript, angular, visual-studio-2015, momentjs

I have a visual studio 2015 project using angular2 2.0.0-rc.4, typescript 1.8.7 and momentjs and when I try to build the project I get 2 compilation errors for moment.d.ts. I tried typescript compiler avoid to compile that file with no luck.

this is my tsconfing.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

The errors that I got:

```
C:/Projects/MyProject/src/MyProject/node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts(210,22): error TS1110: Type expected.
C:/Projects/MyProject/src/MyProject/node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts(218,52): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

And I am importing moment like this in my .ts

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before? Thanks.

Comment: Did you use this command when you installed it?: typings install moment --save

Comment: Yes, I did. Even I uninstalled it and reinstalled it again

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the versions of Typescript and Moment that you have installed are compatible.

I was running typescript v 1.8.x and had installed the most recent version of moment (v 2.17.0 at the time of writing) and got the same errors. [Moment v2.17.0 was updated to be compatible with Typescript 2.0](https://github.com/moment/moment/commit/2cfb22b779ed5c35dc590994715d73b6f650b74d), and has some types that typescript 1.8.x doesn't recognize, and throws the type errors shown.

You can either update typescript to 2.0 (which may break some other things) or explicitly install moment v2.16.0

Assuming you use npm:

`npm install typescript@2.0 --save-dev`

---or---

`npm install moment@2.16.0 --save`

Note: you may need to reinstall typings for moment if you downgrade versions. I was getting type errors not only in `moment.d.ts` but in also in the moment typings file. Running the following resolved this for me.

`typings install moment=npm:moment --save-dev`